# MySQL scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb are not executed

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to create multiple databases when a MySQL container starts up.
According to https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/pull/18, I can mount or copy my scripts in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` of the image and they will be executed automatically on start up.

However my scripts are not at all executed. Seems like the `docker-entrypoint.sh` doesn't see files in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql
ADD script.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sql
RUN chmod -R 775 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD mypass
```

This is my `script.sql`:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
CREATE DATABASE mydb2;
```

I build and run the container:

```
$ docker build -t mysql .
$ docker run -v data_volume:/var/lib/mysql --name somedb -d mysql
```

When I access the container in tty I can see that the `script.sql` is in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` but is not executed.

I have seen the `docker logs -f somedb` output but there is no error.

I have tried with `.sh` file, I also have tried with Maria-db, the result is the same.

What could be the problem?

Comment: This blog helped me to make this work for me: https://medium.com/@lvthillo/customize-your-mysql-database-in-docker-723ffd59d8fb

Answer (score 98, accepted):

## Solution

You should **clear** `data_volume` BEFORE running the container and the SQL files will be executed.

---

This volume `data_volume` can be removed by using command:

> `docker volume rm data_volume`

The root cause of your problem can be found in `docker-entrypoint.sh`. When you run a MySQL container, it checks if MySQL directory `/var/lib/mysql` exist or not.
If the directory doesn't exist (running it the first time), it will run your SQL files.

```bash
if [ ! -d "$DATADIR/mysql" ]; then
    // Some other logic here

    for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
        case "$f" in
            *.sh)     echo "$0: running $f"; . "$f" ;;
            *.sql)    echo "$0: running $f"; "${mysql[@]}" < "$f"; echo ;;
            *.sql.gz) echo "$0: running $f"; gunzip -c "$f" | "${mysql[@]}"; echo ;;
            *)        echo "$0: ignoring $f" ;;
        esac
        echo
    done
```

You can get more details from MySQL `docker-entrypoint.sh` [*source*](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) file.

Comment: There is a slight language barrier above, so I wanted to add to this solution to clarify it a bit, as it is the correct one:

If the mysql data volume exists, it will not be overwritten by the SQLs in the entry db. For me, this meant doing `rm /my/data/volume`, as it was a disposable one. After that, things ran as they should.

Comment: Wow, i spent hours on this one. Thank you for this!

Comment: Thank @TarekLoubani for the explanation.I've updated the answer also

Comment: THANK YOU! I ran into this as well

Comment: My import worked fine until I switched from `mysql:5.7` to `mysql-server:5.7`.

It turns out that the entrypoint in the server image does not include the line to process .sql.gz extensions.

Comment: @Zaq, I think we should check this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/main/mysql-server/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh) file. It supports `*.sh` and `*.sql` files only.

Comment: you saved us all !

Answer (score 29):

So I had the same issue for hours, and then decided to look into docker-entrypoint.sh. It turns out that the script checks for $DATADIR/mysql, typical /var/lib/mysql and skips the rest of the code if the datadir exists, incl. docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

So what I did was make a simple init.sh file to remove the datadir then start docker.

docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
  - ./docker/mysql/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

init.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf mysql_data
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

And of course add `-d` to `docker-compose` once I see it works as expected.

Comment: where did you add the init.sh file?

Comment: @GeorgeGeorgitsis: If the Docker image finds any files with the extensions .sh or .iql inside of the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder, it will execute them. 

I my case the init.sh it located inside ./docker/mysql/scripts/

Comment: My 5 cents: Mind that you should include execution in the permissions for the `init.sh` file on the host - otherwise you could get an error like:
`/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Permission denied`

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same issue with the mariadb image (version: 10.4) and I solved it by making sure my container data volume is empty from any files or directories when I create the container from scratch.

This is my docker compose file:

```
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ********
    volumes:
    - ./storage/db:/var/lib/mysql:rw
    - ./app/db/SQL:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:rw
    ports:
    - 3306:3306/tcp
```

For me I just had to make sure this path: './storage/db' is empty from files. Please notice that the directory has to exists but be empty.

Comment: How did you empty `./storage/db`?

Comment: You can try and use a new docker volume or delete all content of your data mounted directory

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I solved it by changing directory owner before starting entrypoint script. Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.7.17
ADD scripts/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

CMD ["mysqld", "--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"]
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and like @Ricky suggested above the root cause was the volume being non empty. I ran the command `docker volume ls` to check if the volume was still present before running my `docker-compose up` and sure enough the volume was there. I deleted the volume using `docker volume rm <volume name>` and ran the docker-compose and voila the script I had in the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` had run and I had my data in my database. I would say don't worry about the chmod stuff (as some people have suggested) until you make sure the volume is non-existent before running the docker-compose. In case that doesn't work, you can try playing around with the file permissions.

This is what I have permissions wise in my working container in case anybody is wondering -

Permission on `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

```
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4.0K Nov 16 01:52 docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

and the following on the sql scripts -

```
root@f0a4da202f39:/opt/app# ls -lh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
total 12K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12K Nov 15 22:14 Henry.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

As per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67435932/15926221

If you're using "MYSQL_USER: root" as the env variable in mysql/mariadb, this can be the cause of the problem, because the root user was already pre-created.

Comment: That was the problem on my side!! Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

not really an answer to that behavior but i usually do it like this:

```
RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d && mv myScript.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/myScript.sql
```

don't think there's anything wrong with your code but who knows.
i suppose you checked 775 is the correct owner?
btw im using FROM mysql:5

Comment: This configuration didn't solve the problem. I have checked that the file is executable.
I guess the problem is in the data_volume. I keep working on it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved the issue yet?

A simple workaround is to use absolute path when reading files in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

I made my test using the default config of: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/Dockerfile#L70

The docker-entrypoint.sh is first moved to /usr/local/bin before execution.

Then it comes to reading files in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/, but the following:

```
for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
```

doesn't seem to find anything.

If you replace it with:

```
for f in /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
```

and then make sure the folder is populated by the Dockerfile command:

```
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

COPY docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN chmod -R +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

From there, build a test statement in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/test.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE `test`;
```

Finally build and run the image and you should see your database created.

Comment: You mean editing mysql's Dockerfile? If so, I hope there is a better solution.