# Docker-Compose and Postgres Extensions

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose file. Is there any easy way to get a postgres extension installed? I'm trying to install `pg_trgm`.

Edit: I now have two dockerfiles and an install script. It doesn't seem to be working when I run `docker-compose up build`

`Internal server error: pq: operator does not exist: character varying % unknown`

```
services:
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: db/Dockerfile
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=x
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=x
      - POSTGRES_DB=x

  api:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        app_env: ${APP_ENV}
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/x/y/z
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

db/Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres
COPY db/install-extensions.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

db/install-extensions.sql

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;
```

Comment: There is an example for adding an extension in a Dockerfile mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/postgres/#additional-extensions): [Github](https://github.com/appropriate/docker-postgis/blob/f6d28e4a1871b1f72e1c893ff103f10b6d7cb6e1/10-2.4/Dockerfile).

Comment: You need to write your own Dockerfile that simply extends from "postgres" and installs the extension. Then you build that dockerfile in the docker-compose

Comment: @Mihai made an edit if you could take a look.

Comment: Put the sql file at the same level as Dockerfile. Then in docker file remove "db/". Also you can remove the "context" declaration in docker-compose.

Comment: @Mihai they are at the same level– for whatever reason I get a 'file not found' if I don't include the db/

Comment: Did you remove the context declaration? You can try and build directly the dockerfile for a test

Comment: @Mihai tried removing the context and got this: `Service db has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.`

Comment: Looks like if data exists the script is ignored. That is why it wasn't working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52715521/5509839

Comment: Indeed you have to always remove the data volume if you want to initialize the database

Comment: my problem with the sql file is that it didn't add the extension to the particular database. The solution by @paul-wheeler below worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
FROM postgres
COPY ./install-extensions.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

and remove db from your file.

OR you can write

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: unit
      POSTGRES_USER: unit
      POSTGRES_DB: unit
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

then

1. create directory scripts
2. put your .sql or .sh file
3. remove created containers docker-compose rm -v
4. start docker docker-compose up --build
5. in logs you must see something like this:

[created_extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIqPX.png)

Comment: I have tested this and while it does seem to run the `CREATE EXTENSION` command it is ineffective. The extension functions (i.e. `SIMILARITY()`) are still not useable when the server has started.

Answer (score 2):

You can add it via the environment variable under POSTGRES_EXTENSIONS:
like this

```
    version: "3.1"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: unit
      POSTGRES_USER: unit
      POSTGRES_DB: unit
      POSTGRES_EXTENSIONS: pg_trgm ,another_extension
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

make sure you separate your extensions with comma

Comment: using this and the script worked perfectly.

Comment: There is no need for POSTGRES_EXTENSIONS as @Alma_Z suggested works perfectly.

Comment: The symbol `POSTGRES_EXTENSIONS` doesn't even exist in the official postgres docker source repo https://github.com/docker-library/postgres (and this environmental variable doesn't work for me). How are you supposed to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure precisely why but in order to get this working I had to use a shell script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "enabling pg_trgm on database $POSTGRES_DB"
psql -U $POSTGRES_USER --dbname="$POSTGRES_DB" <<-'EOSQL'
  create extension if not exists pg_trgm;
EOSQL
echo "finished with exit code $?"
```

possibly because I was overriding the default database and user name.

Comment: Yep, me too. For the sql solution it didn't add it to the specific database, which was the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer about docker-entrypoint-initdb.d is good, but didn't work for me since I already had a database. Actually, in this case, use your migration system to add an extension.

For django, the migration will look something like this:

```
from django.db import migrations

def create_third_party_extension(apps, schema_editor):
    schema_editor.execute("CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;")


def drop_third_party_extension(apps, schema_editor):
    schema_editor.execute("DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS pg_trgm;")


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('core', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_third_party_extension, reverse_code=drop_third_party_extension, atomic=True)
    ]
```