# how to install postgres extension with docker on django project

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I want to add full text search to my Django project and I used PostgreSQL and docker,so want to add extension pg_trgm to PostgreSQL for trigram similarity search. how should I install this extension with dockerfile?

[In shared my repository link.](https://github.com/amirkh75/D3ByExample/tree/master/Blog)

```
FROM python:3.8.10-alpine
WORKDIR /Blog/


ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev


RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' ./entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

> docker-compose

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/Blog
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=helo
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=helo
      - POSTGRES_DB=helo
    
volumes:`enter code here`
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741735/docker-compose-and-postgres-extensions as it looks to be the same sort of question and might have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this the hard way!

```sh
$ sudo docker-compose exec db bash
$ psql -U username -d database
$ create extension pg_trgm;
```

> This is not a good method, because you have to be careful and reinstall it every time the image is created.

or

use default django solution:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#trigramextension

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import TrigramExtension

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    ...

    operations = [
        TrigramExtension(),
        ...
    ]
```

Comment: I've been struggling trying to install this through docker-compose for ages, doing all sorts of weird stuff manipulating databases on startup, but this was all I needed!! thank you!! This applies to everything in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/

Answer (score 1):

For someone who is building a PostgreSQL image from scratch another cleaner way would be to include all extensions that he/she wants to build the image with by specifying them under environments variable using , POSTGRES_EXTENSIONS: (inside docker-compose.yml file)

```
    services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/Blog
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: helo
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: helo
      POSTGRES_DB: helo
      POSTGRES_EXTENSIONS: pg_trgm ,your_other_extension
    
volumes:`enter code here`
  postgres_data:
```

Replace your_other_extension with the name of the extension you want to install, and make sure to separate them with a comma.

In addition to POSTGRES_PASSWORD, POSTGRES_DB, POSTGRES_USER, and POSTGRES_EXTENSIONS, you can set other environment variables for the PostgreSQL container as well. Here are some commonly used ones:

POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD -The authentication method used for connecting to the database

PGDATA: - The location of the PostgreSQL data directory

POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: Additional arguments to pass to the initdb command when creating the database cluster